How to assign common equation numbers for two lines of initial and boundary conditions
Question: I have a set of initial and boundary conditions in two lines, how can I give common equation number to them?
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
left=1.00in,
right=1.00in,
top=1.00in,
bottom=1.00in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
$u = u_{w}=ax^n$, $T=T_{w}$, $C=C_{w}$, $v=0$ as $y \to 0$

$T \to T_{\infty}$, $C \to C_{\infty}$, $u \to u_{e}=bx$, as $y \to \infty$
\end{document}


Off-topic: left=1.00in,right=1.00in,top=1.00in,bottom=1.00in may be expressed more parsimoniously as margin=1in.

I agree with your comment.

I suggest you use a two-row split environment (provided by the amsmath package, which is loaded automatically by the mathtools package) inside an equation environment.
Depending on your formatting preferences, you may want to align the rows (by inserting & symbols) either on the word "as" (see below) or at the start of each row.

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u = u_{w}=ax^n,\ T=T_{w},\ C=C_{w},\ v=0 
  &\quad\text{as}\quad y \to 0 \\
T \to T_{\infty},\ C \to C_{\infty},\ u \to u_{e}=bx 
  &\quad\text{as}\quad y \to \infty
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's follow-up question: To place just this display-math group at the far-left edge of the text block, I suggest you (a) change the inner split environment to an aligned environment and (b) change the outer equation environment to an flalign environment. (The aligned and flalign environments are also provided by the amsmath package.)

The vertical lines at the edges of the screenshot are there because the geometry package was loaded with the option showframe, to show the edges of the text block You will likely want to omit this option in your real document.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry} % remove 'showframe' option in real document
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\begin{aligned}
u = u_{w}=ax^n,\ T=T_{w},\ C=C_{w},\ v=0 
  &\quad\textup{as}\quad y \to 0 \\
T \to T_{\infty},\ C \to C_{\infty},\ u \to u_{e}=bx 
  &\quad\textup{as}\quad y \to \infty
\end{aligned} && % no need here for anything to the right of '&&'
\end{flalign} 

\end{document}


It looks perfect. Great answer. Thank you so much for your help.

One question: Is it possible to align them on the left side?

@SandyM - To left-align the rows, simply place the & alignment markers at the start of each row instead of before \text{as}.

It doesn't; I tried your suggestion.

@SandyM - Please clarify, then, what you mean by “align [the equations] on the left side”.

figure is added. Just asking that question, is it possible or not?

@SandyM - The answer is "yes". Please see the addendum I just posted.

Great. Thanks again

I'd define a suitable environment, so you can delay the final decisions about the alignment to the left margin (which I cannot recommend).
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for filler text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{boundaryconditions}{O{0pt}b}{%
  \begin{flalign}
  \hspace{#1} % optional indentation
  \begin{aligned}
  #2
  \end{aligned}&&&
  \end{flalign}
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[22][1-3]
\begin{boundaryconditions}\label{first}
& u = u_{w}=ax^n,\ T=T_{w},\ C=C_{w},\ v=0 && \text{as } y \to 0 \\
& T \to T_{\infty},\ C \to C_{\infty},\ u \to u_{e}=bx, && \text{as } y \to \infty
\end{boundaryconditions}
\lipsum[23][1-3]
\begin{boundaryconditions}[2em]\label{second}
& u = u_{w}=ax^n,\ T=T_{w},\ C=C_{w},\ v=0 && \text{as } y \to 0 \\
& T \to T_{\infty},\ C \to C_{\infty},\ u \to u_{e}=bx, && \text{as } y \to \infty
\end{boundaryconditions}
\lipsum[24][1-3]

I don't really like \eqref{first} and would prefer \eqref{second}. Just change
the default value for the optional argument.

\end{document}


Here's an example of what I mean: suppose you decide that the conditions should be indented by \parindent, but one of the set of conditions needs a bit more room.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for filler text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{boundaryconditions}{O{\parindent}b}{%
  \begin{flalign}
  \hspace{#1} % optional indentation
  \begin{aligned}
  #2
  \end{aligned}&&&
  \end{flalign}
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[22][1-3]
\begin{boundaryconditions}\label{first}
& u = u_{w}=ax^n,\ T=T_{w},\ C=C_{w},\ v=0 && \text{as } y \to 0 \\
& T \to T_{\infty},\ C \to C_{\infty},\ u \to u_{e}=bx, && \text{as } y \to \infty
\end{boundaryconditions}
\lipsum[23][1-3]
\begin{boundaryconditions}[0pt]\label{second}
& u = u_{w}=ax^n,\ T=T_{w},\ C=C_{w},\ v=0 && \text{as } y \to 0 \\
& T \to T_{\infty},\ C \to C_{\infty},\ u \to u_{e}=bx, && \text{as } y \to \infty
\end{boundaryconditions}
\lipsum[24][1-3]

In \eqref{first} the margin is \texttt{\string\parindent}, but
in~\eqref{second} I pretend that the conditions are too long
and require more room.

\end{document}



Extraordinary way.. I salute to you for the reply in such a wonderful way.
